# Obtener la versión más reciente de un archivo en un servidor

Tags: javascript, laravel-8

Tengo una pagina alojada en un servidor. Siendo aún más especifico, esta construida con Laravel 8.

Si le subo un archivo a `public/`, y luego accedo a la ruta del archivo por su URL, me descarga el archivo.

Ejemplo: subo `Prueba.xlsx` a `midominio.com/public/`. La URL para descargar dicho archivo seria `midominio.com.mx/public/Prueba.xlsx`.

El problema viene cuando sobrescribo dicho archivo pues cuando accedo a `midominio.com.mx/public/Prueba.xlsx` me descarga la versión anterior del archivo.

No importa si uso JavaScript, o si ingreso la URL manualmente, a menos que pase un día entero, me sigue descargando la versión anterior del archivo.

El problema solo se presenta si utilizo el mismo navegador. Si uso otro, el problema no ocurre la primera vez, pero luego si. Tampoco se presenta si uso el modo incognito.

Esto es un problema de Cache, ¿no? Pero no importa cuantas veces presione `Ctrl + F5` me sigue descargando el mismo archivo.

Para subir archivos estoy usando FTP mediante FileZila. Allí no tengo problemas pues si actualizo el archivo y luego lo descargo, me descarga la ultima versión sin problemas.

¿Qué me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Usa las cabeceras, para eso están. Hay una cabecera de [control de caché](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) que le indica al navegador si debe guardar una copia en caché del recurso solicitado o no. En tu caso debes usar la directiva [`no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#no-cache). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Seguí el consejo que Mauricio Contreras me comento, y durante mi investigación me encontré con [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643591/response-download-header-no-cache-must-revalidate) en el sitio en ingles, el cual hasta replique. Sin embargo, el problema persistió. No se si esto sea algo del servidor o que.

Al final termine por simplemente añadir un `? + Date.now()` en JavaScript a la URL de descarga y así ya no he tenido más problemas.